# Critique Personal Logo

Tags: logo, color-theory, critique, design-principles

### Heyo guys. **I'm looking to get my personal logo critiqued**

The logo would represent the intersection between engineering and design and set an overarching design language for what I place it on:

- *Circular background logo:* profile pics, favicons, anything small
- *Long width logo:* works well with lines of text, add a pic on top...
- *Logo top + Type bottom:* works with namecard

*Note: the circular encasing simulates a profile pic container*

Not sure if the shape, balance and colors are good. Alternative suggestions will be considered.

---

### **Original: v0** (just a relative measure)

[image]

---

### **Edit: v1**

Reduced teal color in dark background, suggested by [@Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/24553/janus-bahs-jacquet)

[image]

---

Comment: It’s hard to know whether the associations the logo gives match your profile, since you don’t mention what it is you’re actually making a logo _for_ exactly. But as a general comment, I like it. I find it well-balanced, an easily-recognisable shape that’s not easily confused with anything else I can think of. The colours work well, though I think the darker blue could be less teal. Association-wise, it makes me think of communication (looks like chain links) and problem solving (looks like an _opened_ lock or chain link) more than graphic design; but they’re not incompatible spheres.

Comment: The logo would represent me and the work I do in tight spaces and set an overarching design language for what I place it on. This includes small profile pics,
website, namecard... etc

The link association was interesting. I didn't see that. I'm 100% trying to convey problem solving in terms of technical interests (engineering stuff). I guess the "design feel" is kinda lacking when the logo is standalone. But "design" could also be conveyed through the website, namecard... what ever I place it on.

Colorwise I do agree that the dark blue could do with a bit of tuning.

Comment: It looks nice to me! The circle version is not necessary in my opinion. The logo icon itself is balanced and complete.

Comment: @MengLinMaker For the record, I meant the darker of the two blues used in the ‘link’ itself, not the navy blue background. I didn’t see that as part of the logo, just samples of the logo on different backgrounds. Similarly (@Vikas), I understood the circle version to be an example of the logo as it would look in a circular space, such as in an Instagram avatar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yeah if the purpose of circle is to show how it would look on circular container like on Twitter and Instagram, it's fine. I just meant if it's part of logo, I would personally prefer the version without circle.

Comment: Yep. I can confirm that the circle is used to emulate a typical profile pic container. The logo itself is the upside-down love-heart thing. The text versions are suited for larger prints.

Answer (score 3):

Overall I think it's very well made.

In general, **nice work**.

These comments are more "nit picky" than anything. I don't think there's any issue anywhere in the mark that immediately struck be as poor or needed fixing. I'd be pleased with myself if I created your mark.

---

I do think the application inside the circle just distracts from the mark in general and should be avoided where possible. The mark stands on its own just fine. No need for the encompassing shape.

---

I can't really comment on the ***colors***. I think your choices are pleasing. Any color choice is more about you and your personality. It's rare to have a "wrong" color combinations in a personal mark. The blue/teals are nice and convey a somewhat "laidback" attitude, but the strength and simplicity of the icon itself still seems to convey a "professional" or "serious" mindset. At least to me.

---

I'm not a huge fan of the ***type*** "Meng Lin" - It's *not* bad in any way. It's simply uninteresting. Admittedly, I have a *personal pet peeve* regarding branding that's just an icon placed above a typeset font. If one is going to flex some creativity for the icon, the same care should be given to the type. I don't find much interest if I can choose a font from a type menu and match your logo font exactly. But again, I **don't** think type is bad in *any way* in your mark. it's simply not very memorable on its own.

---

The ***iconography*** is great. I would perhaps focus on *construction* at this point. Merely to refine everything. There seems to be some very minute discrepancies in widths and rounding. *However*, what I'm seeing may just be due to posting the raster format, and some distortion occurred due to that process. But... at this point I would reconstruct with *precision* in mind...

[image]

My only *possible* point of **exploration** would be in perhaps rounding the 4 sharp corners ever so slightly. Only a small % of the other rounding so they aren't 90° corners. **This is merely a matter of preference, though.** If you like the sharp corners then I wouldn't argue with you about them. I think it works either way. The slight rounding of those 4 corners *should* soften things just a hair as well as make the mark "feel" a bit more *fluid* overall. So, I'd use a circle that is 25% the size of the inner, smaller, circle in the grid.

[image]

---

Again, these are really **minor** things and I only mention them because you asked. `:)`

Comment: The circle is just to show the boundary of things like Instagram or Twitter avatars – it’s not part of the logo (this was clarified in a comment).

Comment: Thanks for the quality feedback.

Looks like there isn't much point making any changes to color, and overall shape. I'm glad that it doesn't look too serious, but also not too relaxed either.

With the type, I simply chose something very geometric to complement the logo. The font is "Outfit". Also thought about using "Lexend" which has a few quirks here and there. But I did think also think about a more custom font. Honestly, not too sure about typography at the moment. What I've chosen is probably the safest choice I can think of. 

Refining construction is probably exactly what I need!

Comment: @Scott I constructed the logo in a slightly different way. What you did by merging the center points of the curves really simplifies the design and feels more confident. In all seriousness, **I like your construction much better.**

Comment: @Scott May I take inspiration `:)` ? Not sure if I could even improve it anymore. Honestly perfectionism lesgo!

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, minimal and balanced to me. The original is better lookig as long as the edit has too stronge colors.

Comment: Oh haha fair enough, I can kind of see what you mean. I struggle to find a balance. But the old one doesn't look vibrant enough.